# Is there any way to have sound while The Secret World is not the focused program?

Tags: the-secret-world

In a number of other games I play, there is an option in the Sound menu or similar that allows me to still hear my sounds even when alt-tabbed out of the game. Generally, this option is something like "Allow Sound while Alt-Tabbed" or "Allow Sound while Not Focus". The Secret World's *Audio Options* menu is rather sparse, and doesn't have such an option, however. I was also unable to find a similar option in any of the other option menus.

Therefore, **is it possible to still hear my game sounds while alt-tabbed out of The Secret World?** Use of a Funcom-approved UI mod or in-game console commands is okay, I'd just like to be able to hear things while alt-tabbed.

Comment: Apparently not: http://forums.thesecretworld.com/showthread.php?t=44753 -- and UI mods can't affect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact you cannot : its a feature implemented in the Dreamworld game engine all the Funcom MMOs are built upon.

Having worked myself at Funcom on Age of Conan, I can tell you that playing the game in windowed mode and reducing it (not switching to an other program, but reducing it in the task bar) was working at that time (maybe they have "corrected" that kind of bug since ?).

But I doubt it ever worked on the Secret World, since the Secret World always had the new features & bugs fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight. :) What a silly limitation to hard-code in. "Feature" my foot.